# How to verify the parameter of an action method with MVCContrib Route TestHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib-testhelper

I have an action method which has pagination object as parameter

```
  public override ActionResult Index(Paging paging) 
  {
        .......
        return View(...);
  }
```

So how could I verify the url to match action method and it's parameter? like below

```
Paging paging = new DefaultPaging();
"/Search".ShouldMapTo<SearchController>(action => action.Index(paging));
```

**Update**

Here is how the route definition looks like, Page,PageSize and Sort are member of the Paging class

```
routes.MapRoute(controller.Name, string.Format("{0}/{{Page}}/{{PageSize}}/{{Sort}}", controller.Name),
                       controller.Index().AddRouteValues(new DefaultPaging()));
```

Comment: Could you show your route definitions?

Comment: Updated the question with route definition